# Topologies on a finite set. An open problem?

Tags: general-topology

Some time ago an eminent professor told me about an OPEN problem: **Number of possible topologies on a finite set?** I was excited about the idea of solving this problem but could not. This was more difficult than I had thought.

Does anyone know whether this problem has been solved?

Comment: There is [this](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/8970/number-of-valid-topologies-on-a-finite-set-of-n-elements) on mathoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

The question is asked (and have several good answers) in mathoverflow:

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/8970/number-of-valid-topologies-on-a-finite-set-of-n-elements

Comment: Thanks you very much, John and Dan Robertson.